# Angular 1.X - Accessing controller variable through directive using $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

Within a controller I have an ajax call that populates *$scope.main_data*. I want to within a directive get that data when it populates. However the two issues I'm having is:

1. I cannot seem to access *$scope.main_data* from the directive.
2. $scope.watch doesn't seem to work because of this.

How can I print the data from the directive once the data arrives?

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$http',  function($scope, $http) {

$scope.main_data = [];

$http.get("some_url").success( function(data) {
  $scope.main_data = data; 
 });

}]);
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
app.directive('myDir', function($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            items: '=items'
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

           $scope.$watch($scope.main_data ,function(newValue,oldValue){ 

             if (newValue){           
                  console.log($scope.main_data);
             }            

           });

        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div my-dir>
 <div>
</div>
```

The directive in the html exists within the controller but for some reason I can't access the controller scope through $scope but $scope.$parent.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.$watch("main_data" ,function(newValue,oldValue){`? - Even better, why not pass `main_data` in as a 2 way binding, then watch that variable instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it.

```
app.directive('myDir', function($compile, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        items: '=items'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
       $scope.$watch("items",function(newValue,oldValue){ 
         if (newValue){           
              console.log($scope.main_data);
         }            
       });
    }
};
});
```

And html:

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div my-dir items="main_data">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Even though you can "hack" around and access `main_data` using series of`$parent` calls on your scope and using some other methods, just pass it in to your directive with `=` binding, so it will be updated when controller scope is updated. In fact you don't even need $watch in this case, you will always have actual data.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work since the watch method calls twice on page reload. One with the empty data [] and two with the loaded data.

Comment: Anyway it works though if I put - if (newValue && newValue.length != 0){...} God I love javascript......

Comment: you can change it to `<div myDir items='main_data' ng-if='main_data' ...` this way you will only render directive when `main_data` is available